# Run missed cronjobs when computer turns on

Tags: linux, scheduled-tasks, crontab

I have some cronjobs running at certain times of the day but sometimes my computer is switched off when they are scheduled to run.

Is there anyway for these to run as soon as the computer is turned back on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cron` is not designed to do that, there are other tools that will, such as `anacron`.

A workaround is to specify a task twice in the `crontab`, once at the time you want it to happen and again with the time `@reboot` so it will run when the system starts.

If you need a minimum amount of time before this task should run, you can implement that with a wrapper script.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in a 3rd party solution, I wrote a script that will allow you to run a script in a range of time like `8:30pm-3am` every `Saturday-Sunday`. So the script will run whenever the computer gets turned on again. I call it: [LazyCron](https://github.com/SurpriseDog/LazyCron)

I tried to make it easy to use, so you can use natural language inputs instead of messing around with cron format. For example, you can specify multiple time ranges like 1-3am, 5:30-7:30am or date ranges like every 2nd Thursday or sat-sun and it just works.